# Flex-lexer error to build rapidnet stimulator

Tags: flex-lexer, ns-3

I was trying to install rapidnet from website netdb.cis.upenn.edu/rapidnet/ , and after that following instructions from github https://github.com/netdb2017/rapidnet_v1.0, however still faced some error as Script.py should be Python.py(mentioned in github link) and some other problems which i solved using commands

> sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev libssl-dev

however it has some problem with flex-lexer i think which is mentioned in 
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=812974

and getting error as

> /usr/include/FlexLexer.h:160:7: note: candidate: void
>   yyFlexLexer::yy_init_buffer(yy_buffer_state*, std::istream&)
>       void yy_init_buffer( struct yy_buffer_state* b, FLEX_STD istream& s );

And the full error detail is as follows

```
[743/947] cxx: src/rapidnet-compiler/ol-lexer.cc -> build/debug/src/rapidnet-compiler/ol-lexer_1.o
[745/947] cxx: src/rapidnet-compiler/table-store.cc -> build/debug/src/rapidnet-compiler/table-store_1.o
[746/947] cxx: src/rapidnet-compiler/all-values.cc -> build/debug/src/rapidnet-compiler/all-values_1.o
[747/947] cxx: src/rapidnet-compiler/parser-util.cc -> build/debug/src/rapidnet-compiler/parser-util_1.o
src/rapidnet-compiler/ol-lexer.cc: In member function ‘int ns3::rapidnet_compiler::OlLexer::yylex(YYSTYPE*, ns3::rapidnet_compiler::OlContext*)’:
src/rapidnet-compiler/ol-lexer.cc:765:9: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::istream {aka std::basic_istream<char>}’ and ‘std::istream* {aka std::basic_istream<char>*}’)
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:40:0,
                 from src/rapidnet-compiler/ol-lexer.cc:95:
/usr/include/c++/5/istream:58:11: note: candidate: std::basic_istream<char>& std::basic_istream<char>::operator=(const std::basic_istream<char>&)
     class basic_istream : virtual public basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>
           ^
/usr/include/c++/5/istream:58:11: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::istream* {aka std::basic_istream<char>*}’ to ‘const std::basic_istream<char>&’
src/rapidnet-compiler/ol-lexer.cc:768:10: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ and ‘std::ostream* {aka std::basic_ostream<char>*}’)
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:39:0,
                 from src/rapidnet-compiler/ol-lexer.cc:95:
/usr/include/c++/5/ostream:58:11: note: candidate: std::basic_ostream<char>& std::basic_ostream<char>::operator=(const std::basic_ostream<char>&)
     class basic_ostream : virtual public basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>
           ^
/usr/include/c++/5/ostream:58:11: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::ostream* {aka std::basic_ostream<char>*}’ to ‘const std::basic_ostream<char>&’
src/rapidnet-compiler/ol-lexer.cc:1312:46: error: invalid user-defined conversion from ‘std::istream {aka std::basic_istream<char>}’ to ‘std::istream* {aka std::basic_istream<char>*}’ [-fpermissive]
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:44:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:39,
                 from src/rapidnet-compiler/ol-lexer.cc:95:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/basic_ios.h:120:7: note: candidate is: std::basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>::operator void*() const [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>] <near match>
       operator void*() const
       ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/basic_ios.h:120:7: note:   no known conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘std::istream* {aka std::basic_istream<char>*}’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:40:0,
                 from src/rapidnet-compiler/ol-lexer.cc:95:
/usr/include/c++/5/istream: In constructor ‘OLBaseFlexLexer::OLBaseFlexLexer(std::istream*, std::ostream*)’:
/usr/include/c++/5/istream:606:7: error: ‘std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_istream() [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]’ is protected
       basic_istream()
       ^
src/rapidnet-compiler/ol-lexer.cc:1422:75: error: within this context
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:39:0,
                 from src/rapidnet-compiler/ol-lexer.cc:95:
/usr/include/c++/5/ostream:384:7: error: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ostream() [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]’ is protected
       basic_ostream()
       ^
src/rapidnet-compiler/ol-lexer.cc:1422:75: error: within this context
src/rapidnet-compiler/ol-lexer.cc:1424:7: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::istream {aka std::basic_istream<char>}’ and ‘std::istream* {aka std::basic_istream<char>*}’)
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:40:0,
                 from src/rapidnet-compiler/ol-lexer.cc:95:
/usr/include/c++/5/istream:58:11: note: candidate: std::basic_istream<char>& std::basic_istream<char>::operator=(const std::basic_istream<char>&)
     class basic_istream : virtual public basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>
           ^
/usr/include/c++/5/istream:58:11: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::istream* {aka std::basic_istream<char>*}’ to ‘const std::basic_istream<char>&’
src/rapidnet-compiler/ol-lexer.cc:1425:8: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ and ‘std::ostream* {aka std::basic_ostream<char>*}’)
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:39:0,
                 from src/rapidnet-compiler/ol-lexer.cc:95:
/usr/include/c++/5/ostream:58:11: note: candidate: std::basic_ostream<char>& std::basic_ostream<char>::operator=(const std::basic_ostream<char>&)
     class basic_ostream : virtual public basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>
           ^
/usr/include/c++/5/ostream:58:11: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::ostream* {aka std::basic_ostream<char>*}’ to ‘const std::basic_ostream<char>&’
src/rapidnet-compiler/ol-lexer.cc: In member function ‘virtual void OLBaseFlexLexer::switch_streams(std::istream*, std::ostream*)’:
src/rapidnet-compiler/ol-lexer.cc:1471:9: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ and ‘std::ostream* {aka std::basic_ostream<char>*}’)
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:39:0,
                 from src/rapidnet-compiler/ol-lexer.cc:95:
/usr/include/c++/5/ostream:58:11: note: candidate: std::basic_ostream<char>& std::basic_ostream<char>::operator=(const std::basic_ostream<char>&)
     class basic_ostream : virtual public basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>
           ^
/usr/include/c++/5/ostream:58:11: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::ostream* {aka std::basic_ostream<char>*}’ to ‘const std::basic_ostream<char>&’
src/rapidnet-compiler/ol-lexer.cc: In member function ‘virtual int OLBaseFlexLexer::LexerInput(char*, int)’:
src/rapidnet-compiler/ol-lexer.cc:1480:11: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘std::istream {aka std::basic_istream<char>}’
src/rapidnet-compiler/ol-lexer.cc:1480:26: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘std::istream {aka std::basic_istream<char>}’
src/rapidnet-compiler/ol-lexer.cc:1484:6: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘std::istream {aka std::basic_istream<char>}’
src/rapidnet-compiler/ol-lexer.cc:1486:11: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘std::istream {aka std::basic_istream<char>}’
src/rapidnet-compiler/ol-lexer.cc:1489:11: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘std::istream {aka std::basic_istream<char>}’
src/rapidnet-compiler/ol-lexer.cc: In member function ‘virtual void OLBaseFlexLexer::LexerOutput(const char*, int)’:
src/rapidnet-compiler/ol-lexer.cc:1506:14: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’
src/rapidnet-compiler/ol-lexer.cc: In member function ‘virtual void OLBaseFlexLexer::yyrestart(std::istream*)’:
src/rapidnet-compiler/ol-lexer.cc:1800:48: error: no matching function for call to ‘OLBaseFlexLexer::yy_init_buffer(yy_buffer_state*, std::istream*&)’
In file included from src/rapidnet-compiler/ol-lexer.cc:326:0:
/usr/include/FlexLexer.h:160:7: note: candidate: void OLBaseFlexLexer::yy_init_buffer(yy_buffer_state*, std::istream&)
  void yy_init_buffer( struct yy_buffer_state* b, FLEX_STD istream& s );
       ^
/usr/include/FlexLexer.h:160:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘std::istream* {aka std::basic_istream<char>*}’ to ‘std::istream& {aka std::basic_istream<char>&}’
src/rapidnet-compiler/ol-lexer.cc: In member function ‘void OLBaseFlexLexer::yy_load_buffer_state()’:
src/rapidnet-compiler/ol-lexer.cc:1843:7: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::istream {aka std::basic_istream<char>}’ and ‘std::istream* {aka std::basic_istream<char>*}’)
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:40:0,
                 from src/rapidnet-compiler/ol-lexer.cc:95:
/usr/include/c++/5/istream:58:11: note: candidate: std::basic_istream<char>& std::basic_istream<char>::operator=(const std::basic_istream<char>&)
     class basic_istream : virtual public basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>
           ^
/usr/include/c++/5/istream:58:11: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::istream* {aka std::basic_istream<char>*}’ to ‘const std::basic_istream<char>&’
src/rapidnet-compiler/ol-lexer.cc: In member function ‘virtual yy_buffer_state* OLBaseFlexLexer::yy_create_buffer(std::istream*, int)’:
src/rapidnet-compiler/ol-lexer.cc:1872:26: error: no matching function for call to ‘OLBaseFlexLexer::yy_init_buffer(yy_buffer_state*&, std::istream*&)’
In file included from src/rapidnet-compiler/ol-lexer.cc:326:0:
/usr/include/FlexLexer.h:160:7: note: candidate: void OLBaseFlexLexer::yy_init_buffer(yy_buffer_state*, std::istream&)
  void yy_init_buffer( struct yy_buffer_state* b, FLEX_STD istream& s );
       ^
/usr/include/FlexLexer.h:160:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘std::istream* {aka std::basic_istream<char>*}’ to ‘std::istream& {aka std::basic_istream<char>&}’
src/rapidnet-compiler/ol-lexer.cc: At global scope:
src/rapidnet-compiler/ol-lexer.cc:23:25: error: prototype for ‘void OLBaseFlexLexer::yy_init_buffer(YY_BUFFER_STATE, std::istream*)’ does not match any in class ‘OLBaseFlexLexer’
src/rapidnet-compiler/ol-lexer.cc:1902:10: note: in expansion of macro ‘yyFlexLexer’
In file included from src/rapidnet-compiler/ol-lexer.cc:326:0:
/usr/include/FlexLexer.h:160:7: error: candidate is: void OLBaseFlexLexer::yy_init_buffer(yy_buffer_state*, std::istream&)
  void yy_init_buffer( struct yy_buffer_state* b, FLEX_STD istream& s );
       ^
Waf: Leaving directory `/home/ali/Downloads/rapidnet_v1.0-master/build'
Build failed
 -> task failed (err #1): 
    {task: cxx ol-lexer.cc -> ol-lexer_1.o}
```

I don't know what to do with it.Can anyone help me to solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

This is a Flex version issue. In this [patch](https://github.com/westes/flex/commit/336a1deaa57975f34cd732d656d1c0cbe3d5233a#diff-cc6ee351a5d4a43ac354a3b81e41eea8) `istream*` are changed to `istream&`. I guess the RapidNet is developed on an older version of Flex, so it assumes `yyin` is declared as `istream*`.

**My solution**: substitute the `/usr/include/FlexLexer.h` in my machine with this older version of [file](https://panthema.net/2007/flex-bison-cpp-example/flex-bison-cpp-example-0.1.3/doxygen-html/FlexLexer_8h-source.html).

(Credit to Harshal Lehri, who is one of the contributors of RapidNet. I emailed him and he pointed me to the file.)